# displaying disk space usage of the current directory excluding size of subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to write a command to display the disk space usage the current directory excluding the size of subdirectories. The following image describes the files and directories of the current directory:

[image: tree diagram of three files with one subdirectory which contains three more files.]

```
du ./ --exclude='./file*'
```

output will be :

```
4 ./dir1

4    .
```

I am getting first output but not second.

Comment: Please clarify whether the desired size should include the sizes of *File[1-3]*, **or** *File[4-6]*.

Comment: No it won't include size  of file [1-3]

Comment: Please clarify whether the desired size should include the sizes of *File[4-6]*.

Answer (score 3):

```
du -Sd 1
```

Output will be:

```
4 ./dir1

4 .
```

Comment: Indeed, using the `-d depth` flag is what is being asked for here and the best solution imo.

Comment: Not sure about `-S` though, it is even considered an illegal option on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the current directory is */tmp/foo*, which has no files, except for a single directory */tmp/foo/bar*, into which is put a copy of `bash` (1113504 bytes).  Running the `tree` util:

```
tree --du "$(pwd)"
```

...reports:

```
/tmp/foo
└── [    1117600]  bar
    └── [    1113504]  bash

     1121696 bytes used in 1 directory, 1 file
```

To get the size in bytes of */tmp/foo*, (but not */tmp/foo/bar*), this works:

```
du -bSd 1 "$(pwd)" | grep -w "$(pwd)$"
```

Output:

```
4096    /tmp/foo
```

The same line of code can be reused, just `cd` to *any* directory:

```
cd foo/bar/
du -bSd 1 "$(pwd)" | grep -w "$(pwd)$"
```

Output:

```
1117600 /tmp/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The command will be :-

$du -S

And the output will be 
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqkC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

du -S ./ --exclude='./file*'

OUTPUT

4    ./dir1
4    ./